# Adding my own name tag to a form component in a partial view - MVC 5.0

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to be able to show a dropdown list for some items in various different locations... I can safely assume that considering it is a dropdown, it will always be used in context with a form and thus a name tag will always be needed. However I wanted to know what's the best practice for this type of problem.

I have the following in a partial view and you can see I have explicitly set the name="Name" which at this moment in time is correctly going to map to the items Class property:

```
@model IEnumerable<TEST.Domain.Entities.James>

@{
    Layout = "";
}

<select name="Name" id="JamesDropdownList">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value="@item.JamesID">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

I may then use this partial view in such a context:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LoadInformation", "James"))
        { 
            <div class="col-lg-9  remove-padding-left">
                @{ Html.RenderAction("DropdownList", "James"); } // This is the partial view being used in a form
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 remove-padding-right">
                @Html.ContinueButton("Continue") // This is a custom button html helper I have created
            </div>
        }
```

So the question is, is this absolutely okay, to declare specifically that the name for this select field is "Name" or is there some special clever razorey way of doing this?

**EDIT**

In fact, don't I have to do     @Html.Hidden("JamesID", item.JamesID) or something in the select? So that when I submit that form, it pushed the JamesID to the controller which looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult LoadInformation(int jamesID)
    {
        // Do something with jamesID
        return View("LoadInformation");
    }
```

You can see i'm a bit confused...

Maybe a better question is, how do I have a re-usable dropdown list that I can use in a form that requires the JamesID from that dropdown list as one of the receiving controller's parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One razory way would be to do this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("JamesDropdownList", new SelectList(Model,"JamesID","Name"))
```

This will assign `JamesDropdownList` to both the `name` and `id` attribute of the dropdown.

Comment: That's great, how do I add an id tag to the html returned from this? (side question, sorry)

Comment: Updated to display an ID

Comment: I get the following error: "Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name" any ideas what that might be?

Comment: Cheers, using that stopped the exception!